# I keep getting an invalid syntax error on line 1 but, everything is written correctly

Tags: python, maya

```
from maya import cmds

sel = cmds.ls(sl=1)

# [u'IK_R_Shoulder', u'FK_R_Shoulder', u'R_Shoulder', u'R_ArmBlender_CtrlGrp']

blend = cmds.createNode("blendColors")

# sel[0] = ik

cmds.connectAttr(sel[0] + '.r', blend + '.color1', f=1 )

# sel[1] = fk

cmds.connectAttr(sel[1] + '.r', blend + '.color2', f=1 )

# sel[2] = skin 

cmds.connectAttr(blend + '.output',sel[2] + '.r',, f=1 )

# sel[3] = blenderCtrl

cmds.connectAttr(sel[3] + '.tx', blend + '.blender')
```

Comment: If you are getting a syntax error then you should show the exact error to us. Also, if you are getting a syntax error then why do you believe that it is written perfectly correct?

Comment: The file may contain invisible characters that interfere with parsing; my first guess is that the file starts with a byte-order mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there are some invisible characters in the file, or a BOM (byte-order mark) if the file is encoded in UTF-8. I would recommend you to load the file into a hex editor and search for such characters.

If this does not help, you could upload the file somewhere and tell us the URI so that we can take a look into it (I would be willing to spend some minutes). When uploading, make sure that you are using a **binary transfer method**, i.e. make sure that the file does not get altered in any way by the transfer software / transfer process itself.

A typical example for this would be when an FTP client running under Windows uploads a file to a place which is on a Linux server, and when thereby the line endings get converted from CR+LF (Windows) to LF only (Linux). So please be careful and double check all settings of the software that actually transfers the file. Otherwise, we will examine a file which is not the same as that one on your hard disk; this would lead us nowhere besides wasting time.

Comment: I'm not too sure, I'll try to look for invisible characters but, I'm following a tutorial with virtually no knowledge in python. Thank you, I will keep you updated!

Comment: Got it fixed! Thanks so much!